# How can I have a variable name in a variable in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I have this code snippet:

```
// Color settings 
.setCat(@x) {
    .cat@{x} {
        .menu-link {
            &.selected, &:hover { background: ~@{"catColor@{x}"}; }
            &:hover:after { border-top-color: ~@{"catColor@{x}"}; }
            &:only-child:after { border-top-color: transparent; }
        }
        .menu-link-submenu { background: ~@{"catColor@{x}"}; }
    }
}

.setCat(1);
```

I hope you can see what I am trying to do. I want the @catColor1 output which LESS then will compile into my hex color stored in that variable.

Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Comment: Your code, although comprehensive, lacks enough explanation. I'd like to help but I would also want you to elaborate this a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest both calls into the string. I've made the processing all go through a single new variable `useColor` (which you *do not have to do*, I just think it looks cleaner):

```
.setCat(@x) {
    .cat@{x} {
        @useColor: ~"@{catColor@{x}}";
        .menu-link {
            &.selected, &:hover { background: @useColor; }
            &:hover:after { border-top-color: @useColor; }
            &:only-child:after { border-top-color: transparent; }
        }
        .menu-link-submenu { background: @useColor; }
    }
}
```

So assuming this LESS:

```
@catColor1: #fff;
@catColor2: #aaa;

.setCat(1);
.setCat(2);
```

Produces this CSS:

```
.cat1 .menu-link.selected,
.cat1 .menu-link:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.cat1 .menu-link:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
.cat1 .menu-link:only-child:after {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
.cat1 .menu-link-submenu {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.cat2 .menu-link.selected,
.cat2 .menu-link:hover {
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
.cat2 .menu-link:hover:after {
  border-top-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.cat2 .menu-link:only-child:after {
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
.cat2 .menu-link-submenu {
  background: #aaaaaa;
}
```